# How to setItem with ruby in the localStorage of a browser before I start my selenium scripts

Tags: javascript, ruby, html, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to setItem in the localStorage of a browser before I start my selenium scripts

I tried to clear the local storage with this command

```
driver.get('javascript:localStorage.clear();')
```

and it works for firefox browser. Then to set an item I tried

```
driver.get('javascript:"window.localStorage.setItem('key','value');", item, value):'
```

Command is executed but the value is not updated.

I am doing this because after setting a value in local storage I able to see a tab in the window which I need to test.

I am using Selenium webdriver and ruby.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
driver.execute_script("<javascript command>")
```

Rather than using `driver.get`? That will actually execute the command. You can also test the command you want to run using the JavaScript console of the Developer Tools.

Comment: I tried this code but still it won't set the resource driver.execute_script("window.localStorage.setItem('discovery_tab','true')"

Comment: Did you try running it in the JS Developer console? You need to make sure you are on a page in order for local storage to work at all.

Comment: Thanks @David Ambler This piece worked driver.execute_script("window.localStorage.setItem('item','value')")

Comment: Excellent! Glad you got it sorted.

Answer (score 0):

I find another way to set and get localStorage through Selenium webdriver.
After installing Watir, you can type code in irb mode:

```
require 'watir'
browser = Watir::Browser.new # Use webdriver to open chrome.
browser.goto 'http://someurl_that_local_storage_accessiable'
local_storage = browser.driver.local_storage
local_storage['key'] = 'value'
```

After this code in irb, you can check your browser if there is an item in localStorage. I am sure it is.

ref: [Selenium WebDriver 3.12.0](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/selenium-webdriver/Selenium/WebDriver/HTML5/LocalStorage)